# javascript date returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

im making it display the time in javascript but when it returns the time it is always undefined. below is the code

im not really sure why it always returns undefined though.

```
$('#bar #time').html(hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix);


var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

//decides if am or pm
var suffix = "AM";
if (hours >= 12) {
    suffix = "PM";
    hours = hours - 12;
}
if (hours == 0) {
    hours = 12;
}

// shows 0 before the minutes if under 10
if (minutes < 10)
minutes = "0" + minutes
```

Comment: the time was returning undefined but i fixed it by moving the jquery call down to the bottom

Answer (score 3):

um, if the code is in that order, you just need to put your first line at the end, as `hours`, `minutes` and `suffix` are all undefined at that point.  Other than that it should work fine (and does, per chrome console).

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely related to your actual question, but `$('#bar #time')` is going to be a fairly inefficient jQuery selector. Since IDs are only used once in your document, searching simply for `$('#time')` will give you the same result and only require the JavaScript engine to to fire `document.getElementById` once rather than twice.

Minor point, but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

No semicolons here

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
```

Comment: Whilst bad practice, not the problem.

Comment: javascriot auto injects semicolons.

Comment: yeah i forgot those, oops. i fixed it though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){


var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

//decides if am or pm
var suffix = "AM";
if (hours >= 12) {
    suffix = "PM";
    hours = hours - 12;
}
if (hours == 0) {
    hours = 12;
}

// shows 0 before the minutes if under 10
if (minutes < 10)
minutes = "0" + minutes

    $('#bar').html(hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix);

});
```

The order in which you print your variables matters,

they were not defined upon printing.